# Can anyone help me fetch a data from a web service with the retrofit?

Tags: java, android, rest, url, retrofit

I am trying to fetch some data from a web service to my android app. I am doing that with a retrofit but I can't get a specific string(joke) value based on id.
I fetch data from this URL: http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3.

When I enter an id as an integer in my app EditText I want with this id retrieve a joke with specific id from web service I mentioned above.

For example when I enter 179 as id in my app EditText and click "Start Retrofit" button I want to get this String value from web service "Chuck Norris? favourite cut of meat is the roundhouse." This string value I want to show as a toast message in my app.

I have already prepared my app code but I need some correction in interface @Query and @GET method and especially in Callback interface success method 
where I want to show a fetched data.

My app has next classes: MainActivity.class, activity_main.xml, Joke.class(I used a POJO to get this class from JSON), JokeInterface.
I have already entered a internet permission in a manifest and  "implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'" in my build.gradle as a dependency.

I put a comment in MainActivity.class and JokeInterface.class where I think that need to enter some code to accomplish my task.

Here is my code:

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Joke Id" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEnterId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter id"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartRetrofit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
        android:text="Start Retrofit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.class:

```
package com.example.dezox.restwebservis;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.dezox.restwebservis.model.Joke;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etEnterId;
    private Button btnStartRetrofit;
    private JokeInterface jokeInterface;
    private Callback<Joke> call;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initWidgets();
        setupListener();
        setupRestAdapter();
    }

    private void initWidgets() {
        etEnterId = findViewById(R.id.etEnterId);
        btnStartRetrofit = findViewById(R.id.btnStartRetrofit);
    }

    private void setupListener() {

        btnStartRetrofit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (etEnterId.getText().length() > 0){
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(etEnterId.getText().toString());
                    getJokeMethod(id);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void getJokeMethod(int id) {
        jokeInterface.getJoke(id, call);
    }

    private void setupRestAdapter(){
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(JokeInterface.ENDPOINT_URL).build();
        jokeInterface = restAdapter.create(JokeInterface.class);

        call = new Callback<Joke>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Joke joke, Response response) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.append(joke.getType()+"\n");
 /*NOTE:               
 Here I need some code for a showing the string data in a toast message*/    


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        };

    }


}
```

Joke.class:(POJO)

```
package com.example.dezox.restwebservis.model;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Joke {

    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private List<Value> value = null;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<Value> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<Value> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}


    class Value {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("joke")
    @Expose
    private String joke;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    private List<String> categories = null;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJoke() {
        return joke;
    }

    public void setJoke(String joke) {
        this.joke = joke;
    }

    public List<String> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<String> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

}
```

JokeInterface.class:

```
package com.example.dezox.restwebservis;

import com.example.dezox.restwebservis.model.Joke;


import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Query;

public interface JokeInterface {

    public static final String ENDPOINT_URL = "http://api.icndb.com/";

    @GET("/")


    void getJoke(@Query("") int id, Callback<Joke> callback);


/*NOTE:
Here I need some code in GET and Query in order to fetch a string
joke with specific id.*/

        }
```

Comment: you couldn't modify the endpoint ??

Comment: I tried many possible solutions but I didn't succeed to get joke string with a specific id. I managed to get "success" from "builder.append(joke.getType()+"\n");" and from "builder.append(joke.getValue()+"\n");" I dont know how to get a string joke from specific id.

Comment: i think you should fillter the value array in the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found out, the url you are calling returned list of jokes. 
"http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3" means - you are getting 3 object of random jokes. So if you call like "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/179", then you will get list of 179 random jokes. In this case 3 and 179 are not ids, they meant to be object count.

If you want only one joke at a time with specific id, you can call like "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/179", this will give you output like -

```
{ "type": "success", "value": { "id": 179, "joke": "Chuck Norris? favourite cut of meat is the roundhouse.", "categories": [] } }
```

and the "value" in "Joke" (POJO class) will not be list anymore,

```
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private Value value;
```

call as,

```
@GET("jokes/{id}")
void getJoke(@Path("id") int id, Callback<Joke> callback);
```

and you can show the returned joke value like,

```
 @Override
        public void success(Joke joke, Response response) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), joke.getValue().getJoke(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Hopes this help!

Comment: @Query("id") is used when you append value to url like ".../jokes/random?id=3". Also you only gave the main URL("http://api.icndb.com/") to RestAdapter, you need to define specific path  in your interface method like @GET("jokes/random/{id}").

Comment: I tried but now I have 2 problems. First I solved and seems that @GET("/jokes/random/{id}") doesn't work without "/" on the beginning.
The second problem is I can't access "joke.getJoke()" because getJoke is in the Value class inside Joke.class.(see Joke class).

Comment: You can try like "joke.getValue().getJoke()". As I mentioned, if you are calling "../jokes/random/{id}", you will get "value" as list and you can't get specific object with id, it will only return random objects. If you call ".../jokes/{id}", you will get "value" as object, and you can get the specific object you want with id.

Comment: your problem is to pick up an id from array in the response ...not from the endpoints ...@Dezo

Comment: Ok. Then you can try like this, for (Value value:  joke.getValue()) { if (value.getId() == 179) // u can show toast with value.getJoke() }. But this does not guaranteed you will find the object with id 179.

Comment: Everything now works fine, but I need to change your @GET("jokes/{id}") in  @GET("/jokes/{id}") because of "/" at the beginning.
Also, I again take json from your "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/179" link and made a new POJO with it and I separated new Joke and Value class in the different file so now I can access "joke.getValue().getJoke()" method.
I tried to enter an id in my app and every possible result was the same as on the server, that means id and string value Chuck Norris joke match.
Can you explain me a little bit about "@Path("id")", what that does?

Comment: Glad that you got. Look at the url "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/179" - here we need to replace 179 with the desire id everytime. That means we are replacing the path value of a URL. In that case we can use @Path("id"). But in this, "http://www.example.com/search?name=test&address=somewhere", we need to pass value for "name" and "address", these are query parameters (after ? sign), so we need to use with @Query("name"), @Query("address"). You can find out more about in official page here - http://square.github.io/retrofit/   :)

Comment: Ok, now I understand if I have "/" in url that means I need to set a path for example "@Path("id")", and if I have url with "?" I need to set a query like this "@Query("name")".